# Como listar somente os documentos em PDF no PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, download

Tenho um código que está listando os arquivos dentro de uma determinada pasta, e *linkando* para download, funcionando tudo certo.

No entanto, eu precisaria que esse código lista-se somente arquivos com o formato `*.pdf`, o código é esse:

```html
<?php 

$diretorio = getcwd(); // pega o endereco do diretorio 
$ponteiro  = opendir($diretorio); // ponteiro que ira percorrer a pasta 



while ($nome_itens = readdir($ponteiro)) { // monta o vetor com os itens da pasta 
    $itens[] = $nome_itens; 
} 
sort($itens); // ordena o vetor de itens 
foreach ($itens as $listar) {  //percorre o vetor para fazer a separacao entre arquivos e pastas 
   if ($listar!=".php" && $listar!=".."){ // retira os itens "./" e "../" para que retorne apenas pastas e arquivos 
           if (is_dir($listar)) { // checa se é uma pasta 
            $pastas[]=$listar; // caso VERDADEIRO adiciona o item ao vetor de pastas 
        } else{  
            $arquivos[]=$listar;// caso FALSO adiciona o item ao vetor de arquivos 
        } 
   } 
}    


$exte_p = array("pdf","PDF");


//foreach($pastas as $listar){// lista as pastas 
   //print "<a href='$listar'><img border=0 src='index_pasta.png'>$listar</a><br>";} 
//

   foreach($arquivos as $listar){// lista os arquivos 
    print "<a href='$listar'>$listar</a><br>";
   

   }

?>
```

Comment: Pode usar a função `glob()` para essa finalidade. Veja no [manual](http://il1.php.net/glob).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a função:

```
glob ( string $pattern [, int $flags = 0 ] ) : array
```

para esta finalidade e especificar que tipo de padrão de arquivos deseja, que no caso seria PDF.

Veja um exemplo:

```
foreach (glob("*.pdf") as $arquivo) {
    echo "arquivo $arquivo\n";
}
```

Consulte o [manual](https://www.php.net/glob) para aprender mais a respeito sobre esta função.

Comment: Muito obrigado, agradeço muito pela ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver com o seguinte código:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.pdf") as $arquivo) {
    echo "<a href='$arquivo'>$arquivo</a><br>" ;        
}
?>
```